# Python equivalent to C# FileStream class

Tags: c#, python, object, filestream

I'm trying to convert some C# code into python and stuck on C#'s filestream class. A filestream is instantiated to load in jpeg data.

```
fs = new FileStream("./preview.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
while(true):
    int length = socketServer.Receive(arrServerRecMsg);
    int offset = arrServerRecMsg[2] * 256 + arrServerRecMsg[3];
    fs.Seek(offset * 1020, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    fs.Write(arrServerRecMsg, 4, arrServerRecMsg.Length - 4);
```

Later on preview is read:

```
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("./preview.jpg", FileMode.Open);
    byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Would the equivalent of python be loading data into an object? How would I perform the offsetting?

Comment: check `open` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just `open` method in python.

`open("./preview.jpg", "w+") == new FileStream("./preview.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)`

It will return a `fileObject`.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it even has a "seek" method

Comment: To replicate `fs.Write(arrServerRecMsg, 4, arrServerRecMsg.Length - 4);` would that be `fo.write(arrServerRecMsg[4:])` in python?

Answer (score 1):

FileObject is the FileStream equivalent in Python,

https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object